# How do keyboard shortcuts work in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, nautilus, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Whenever someone launches file manager from launcher `/usr/bin/nautilus` is executed through `nautilus.desktop`. Now, in nautilus, if the user presses ,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, a new tab is opened. For this to happen, some file or commands must be executed. Where are these files or commands stored?

There are no keyboard-specific executables in `usr/bin/`. In short what does OS do when some keyboard shortcut is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts for nautilus are defined in `~/.config/nautilus/accels` file.

Comment: But, how does it work? It shows a path like `<Actions>/ShellActions/New Tab` but `find ShellActions` says that there is no such directory. Where does that path lead to?

Comment: And, what is the case with other applications? ~/.config lists only some applications

Comment: @nitish That file (`~/.config/nautilus/accels`) is an automated accelerator map dump loaded by Nautilus using Gtk3 (`Gtk.AccelMap.load()`). If you have good knowledge in C++ programming, you should get a look on the [nautilus source code](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13984/where-can-i-find-the-source-of-nautilus) to understand how exactly. In general the shortcuts for an application are defined in its source code.

Comment: @nitish The purpose of `~/.config` directory is for program configuration and user setting files. Not all programs need to keep configuration files in there. That's why you don't see all the apps there.