# How can I make keyboard shortcuts work again?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

All shortcuts don’t work any longer on my Xubuntu 20.04 system.
When I add a new definition, it appears in the file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`, as I found out looking at files which have changed a few minutes ago using

```
find . * -atime -0,01 -type f -printf "%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TT %p\n" | \
sort -r | ssed -R 's/^([^.]+)\.\d+ (.*)$/\1 \2/'
```

I reset all shortcuts to the standard, but even these reset definitions don’t work. I tested it e.g. with **Strg-Alt T** or with **Super T**, which both should open a terminal. (The mouse pointer was on the desktop at that moment, if that matters). Of course the modification timestamp of `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` was updated and its content changed through the reset operation.

**How can I make keyboard shortcuts work again?**

N.B. `appmenu-qt5` mentioned in [an answer to this 10 years old post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372856/how-do-keyboard-shortcuts-work-in-ubuntu) is not present on my system.

Addendum: I found out that the shortcuts of another user work on the same computer. But after copying them to the position in the home directory of the user, whose shortcuts don't work, they still don't work there, even after a reboot.

There must be something else besides `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` preventing all shortcuts from working. **But what is it?**

Answer (score 0):

It's a really mysterious thing: because my computer is a laptop with a touchpad, it happened to me all the time when I was writing that I was writing somewhere else than I meant to, because the mouse pointer had jumped somewhere and probably even marked existing text and writing over it on the next keystroke. This is of course terribly annoying.

As a workaround, I installed `touchpad-indicator` in order to disable the touchpad when a mouse is present. For each user, this app has an individual configuration file `~/.config/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator.conf`. It is written terribly tightly without line breaks and contains an entry `disable_on_typing`. This must be set to

```
"disable_on_typing": false
```

otherwise all shortcuts become ineffective! But then of course, the touchpad does not get deactivated for a short amount of time *after* each keystroke, so this approach seems to be useless. (would it not be necessary to prevent any touchpad-event including its associates mouse keys *around* each keystroke on the keyboard itself?)

I found this when I compared all configuration files of the other user on the same computer, whose shortcuts worked, with mine: a rather tedious but successful job.

Unfortunately one day later no shortcuts worked any longer. Before I had tested, whether `"disable_on_typing": false` and `"disable_on_typing": true` in the configuration file triggered the bug and they did, even across rebooting. But now it looks like not working any longer. There might have bees some other factor which I must have overseen before.